# Resize UIImageView by changing frame

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview, frame

I have added a UIImageView in storyboard with a default image. In the code, I am updating the image at runtime and also adjusting the frame.

```
mainImageView.sd_setImage(with: NSURL(string: urlString) as URL?, completed: {
        (image, error, cacheType, url) in
        self.setPoints()
    })

public func setPoints() {
    mainImageView.frame = CGRect(x:x, y:0, width:(mainImageView.image?.size.width)!/1.7, height:(mainImageView.image?.size.height)!/1.7)
    mainImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    mainImageView.setNeedsDisplay()
    mainImageView.reloadInputViews()
    mainImageView.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
}
```

I read various posts on stack overflow and tried resizing the imageivew using above methods but no luck. Is there any other way for resizing the imageview?

Comment: mainImageView added by auto-layout ?If yes then you should take height and width constraints and manage it.

Comment: mainImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;

You can put this code to your -viewDidLoad method or just above mainImageView.sd_setImage(with:...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should disable pregenerated constraints. The most simple way is to use autoresizing masks instead of constraints for animating view.

```
mainImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

You can put this code to your `-viewDidLoad` method or just above `mainImageView.sd_setImage(with:...`

And last but not least you need to call layoutIfNeeded within the block.

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using autolayout to size your image view, which would explain why manually setting the frame isn't doing anything. You need to modify the constraints that are determining the size of the image view, and then call `mainImageView.layoutIfNeeded()`.